# UITableView with UISegmentedControl

Tags: uitableview

I am going crazy, please someone help me!

I am having a tableview and when a row is selected, I go to detailview. In my detailview I want to have a UISegmentedControl and a table below. Based on the segment that is selected, I want to display appropriate contents in the cells below.

I created a UISubviewClass and In the IB, I placed a UISegmentedControl and a below that, a UITableView. Now where should my view in file's owner point to? If I select tableview, it hides the UISegmentedcontrol. I mapped it to the View below it and for my table view, I mapped the delegate and datasource to file's owner.

Now in my .h file, should i have @interface SegmentViewController : UIViewController or
@interface SegmentViewController : UITableViewController? If I have UITableViewController, it again hides the segmentviewcontroller. If I have it as UIViewController,

[self.tableView reloadData] does not work. I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0):

Everything should be pointing to your File's owner of course, i mean there is were your references are right?

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mySegControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

but why did you subClass the view?